# Efficient Parsing of XML

Tags: c#, xml, optimization

Good day,

I'm writing a program in C# .Net to manage products of my store,

Following a given link I can retrieve an XML file that contains all the possible products that I can list onto my storefront.

The XML structure looks like this :

```
<Product StockCode="103-10440">
    <lastUpdated><![CDATA[Fri, 20 May 2016 17:00:03 GMT]]></lastUpdated>
    <StockCode><![CDATA[103-10440]]></StockCode>
    <Brand><![CDATA[3COM]]></Brand>
    <BrandID><![CDATA[14]]></BrandID>
    <ProdName><![CDATA[BIG FLOW BLOWING JUNCTION FLEX BLOCK, TAKES 32, 40]]>     </ProdName>
    <ProdDesc/>
    <Categories>
        <TopCat><![CDATA[Accessories]]></TopCat>
        <TopCatID><![CDATA[24]]></TopCatID>
    </Categories>
    <ProdImg/>
    <ProdPriceExclVAT><![CDATA[30296.79]]></ProdPriceExclVAT>
    <ProdQty><![CDATA[0]]></ProdQty>
    <ProdExternalURL><![CDATA[http://pinnacle.eliance.co.za/#!/product/4862]]></ProdExternalURL>
</Product>
```

Here are the entries I'm looking for :

- lastUpdated
- StockCode
- Brand
- ProdName
- ProdDesc
- TopCat <--- nested in Categories tag.
- ProdImg
- ProdPriceExclVAT
- ProdQty
- ProdExternalURL

This is all fine to handle , and in-fact I did :

```
public ProductList Parse() {

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(XMLLink);

    XmlNodeList ProductNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Product");
    foreach (XmlNode node in ProductNodeList) {
        Product Product = new Product();

        for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++) {
            if (node.ChildNodes[i].Name == "StockCode") {
                Product.VariantSKU = Convert.ToString(node.ChildNodes[i].InnerText);
            }
            if (node.ChildNodes[i].Name == "Brand") {
                Product.Vendor = Convert.ToString(node.ChildNodes[i].InnerText);
            }
            if (node.ChildNodes[i].Name == "ProdName") {
                Product.Title = Convert.ToString(node.ChildNodes[i].InnerText);
                Product.SEOTitle = Product.Title;
                Product.Handle = Product.Title;
            }
            if (node.ChildNodes[i].Name == "ProdDesc") {
                Product.Body = Convert.ToString(node.ChildNodes[i].InnerText);
                Product.SEODescription = Product.Body;
                if (Product.Body == "") {
                    Product.Body = "ERROR";
                    Product.SEODescription = "ERROR";
                }
            }
            if (node.ChildNodes[i].Name == "Categories") {
                if (!tempList.Categories.Contains(node.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes[0].InnerText)) {
                    if (!tempList.Categories.Contains("All")) {
                        tempList.Categories.Add("All");
                    }
                        tempList.Categories.Add(node.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes[0].InnerText);
                }

                Product.Type = Convert.ToString(node.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes[0].InnerText);
            }
            if (node.ChildNodes[i].Name == "ProdImg") {
                Product.ImageSrc = Convert.ToString(node.ChildNodes[i].InnerText);
                if (Product.ImageSrc == "") {
                    Product.ImageSrc = "ERROR";
                }
                Product.ImageAlt = Product.Title;
            }
            if (node.ChildNodes[i].Name == "ProdPriceExclVAT") {
                float baseprice = float.Parse(node.ChildNodes[i].InnerText);
                double Costprice = ((baseprice * 0.14) + (baseprice * 0.15) + baseprice);
                Product.VariantPrice = Costprice.ToString("0.##");
            }
        }
        Product.Supplier = "Pinnacle";
        if (!tempList.Suppliers.Contains(Product.Supplier)) {
            tempList.Suppliers.Add(Product.Supplier);
        }
        tempList.Products.Add(Product);
        }
    return tempList;
    }
}
```

The problem is however, that this way of doing it, takes about 10 seconds to finish, and this is only just the first of multiple such files that I have to parse.

I am looking for the most efficient way to parse this XML file, getting all the fields's data that I mentioned above.

EDIT : 
I benchmarked the code when running with a pre-downloaded copy of the file, and when downloading the file from the server at runtime :

- With local copy : 5 Seconds.
- Without local copy : 7.30 Seconds.

Comment: Something fishy here. That shouldn't take 10s. You timed that function alone? How big is this XML file? BTW you can put `node.ChildNodes[i].Name` into a switch; there's no need to check the name multiple times if you've already found a match.

Comment: The XML file is about 82k lines with a filesize of 3.2MB - Im retrieving said file from a web-link.

Comment: Clock the time it takes to download separately from the time it takes you to parse the xml

Comment: @KazutoKirigaya I'm loading a 1.2GB file simply using XElement.Load("filename") in less than a minute, odds are the slow part is the downloading part and not the parsing. 82kb is "very very small" in today's term, i suggest using linq to XML (XElement/XDocument) instead of the older XmlDocument objects

Comment: Listen to the people's voice and before rewriting with XmlReader (which can help with memory consumption - rare with parsing perfomance) - find the real reason why it slow with your current code.

Comment: @Evk im going to run some benchmarks on my old code now, working on it as we speak

Comment: @RonanThibaudau i think you may be misreading my comment on the filesize, its 3.3MB ( still not very large ) , with 82000 lines ( 82k lines ) , the filesize is not, however 82kb

Comment: I added benchmarking results to the main question

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong or heavy in your parsing. It just cannot plain-parse 3mb file for 5 seconds. You benchmarking only Parse method above, right? And no other work like working with database involved? What is that "tempList" in your Parse by the way?

Comment: I'm benchmarking ONLY that one method , the tempList is a custom class that defines a list of Product classes ( which contains the ultimate data I'm storing and using throughout the program )

Comment: When using the new parser i created using the code from the below answer - the running time is down to ~2.7 seconds ( when downloading the file at runtime ) , and virtually instantaneous when using a local copy. - Something awful was happening in my old method, just don't know what ;/

Comment: @KazutoKirigaya You're right i missread it, however it's still nearly 1000 times smaller than what i parse so i would drop the XmlReader solution and go with simply XElement.Load + linq query on it for readability, the solution should perform about the same (maybe "slightly" slower)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With large XML files you have to use an XmlReader.  The code below will read one Product at a time.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("filename");
            while(!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "Product")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("Product");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement product = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    string lastUpdated = (string)product.Element("lastUpdated");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 3 MB is not too large IMO

Comment: @jdweng , is this the most efficient way to go about it? - ill replace my current solution with this and test it as well.

Comment: @jdweng, sorry if this is a simple question, but how do I go about getting the nested property that I want to get ( TopCat ) - Is it the same as with the others?

Comment: Not a lot of lines of code.  When reading multiple files of 3MB will start to use a lot of memory and will eventually start to slow down.  My code does use a lot of memory to read one element at a time.  Only was of knowing for sure is to perform a bench test by measuring time.

Comment: Use Descendants instead of Element : product.Descendants("TopCat").FirstOrDefault() and product.Descendants("TopCatID").FirstOrDefault()

Comment: @jdweng, there is no such method I can call upon descendants called FirstOrDefault() ?

Comment: I just tested following line and it works : string topCat = (string)product.Descendants("TopCat").FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Yeah nevermind I didnt have the correct usings ( missed system.linq )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113231/discussion-between-kazuto-kirigaya-and-jdweng).