# Interpret string as hexadecimal and filter non print characters

Tags: c#, xml, algorithm, xmlreader

Edit: I completed the class, but it is much more complex now, so i don't will post it here.
I don't know why but i got a better exception message now: 
'<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attributetoken. line 68, position 22.
So the suggestion with the non print hexadecimal seems to be right. The problem to solve now is: how to interpret and analyse strings as hexadecimal? Than i would be able to write them in a special cdata section.
Greetings

Comment: At which line exactly is the exception? And can you share the EXACT exception message, not a free interpretation.

Comment: I need more of the file to give an answer.  If you using XmlReader use the code that I did at this posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503602/efficient-parsing-of-xml/37503653#comment62503595_37503653.  Why aren't you using the code I gave your on April 23?

Comment: The node is the posted one. To your link: As written above, this is an file indexing program. If you buffer the node, it will lose performance. Iam not sure how much you lose, but wirh 200 000 files, it's   should be noticeable.

Comment: The exception is in german, i will do my best with translating ;)

Comment: My guess is that there are some zero-width or nonprinting characters at the start of the file. Try opening it in a hex editor.

Comment: Thats the problamatic line:20 3C 66 69 6C 65 20 6E 61 6D 65 3D 22 73 65 67 6F 65 5F 73 6C 62 6F 6F 74 22 3E 43 3A 5C 42 6F 6F 74 5C 46 6F 6E 74 73 5C 73 65 67 6F 65 5F 73 6C 62 6F 6F 74 2E 74 74 66 3C 2F 66 69 6C 65 3E Note:It seems that Dour isn't so wrong. If I delete the line, the same exception is thrown at the same position (Line 115 Postion 4)