# How can I skip to an EndElement?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I have the next xml:

```
<work><pageSetup paperSize="9"><a foo="aa"/></pageSetup></work>
```

I run over the elements with:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(myFile.xml))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.Name + " " + reader.NodeType);
        if (reader.Name == "pageSetup") reader.Skip();
    }
 }
```

I want to skip to the < /pageSetup> 
EndElement (when the "cursor" is on < pageSetup> ), but the Skip() method skips over the whole element **and its EndElemet**. (And this is the correct behavior of Skip() method as written in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720634(v=vs.71).aspx:
The Skip method moves over the current element. If the node type is XmlNodeType.Element, calling Skip moves over all of the content of the element and the element end tag.)

What is the suitable method to use in this case?

Comment: then you use textreader and skip the the text "</pagesetup>" but why you want to do this?

Comment: I usually recommend using an xml reader like the solution I gave in following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503602/efficient-parsing-of-xml/37503653#comment62503595_37503653

Comment: @Viru that fails for nested tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just keep calling `Read()` until `Depth` goes back down to the node you start with. Something like this should work (error handling omitted):

```
int startDepth = reader.Depth; // assume you're on the start element
if (!reader.IsEmptyElement) { // if it is an <empty /> element, there is no end
    reader.Read();
    while (reader.Depth > startDepth) reader.Read();
}
```