# read repetitive blocks using XmlReader c#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I have below xml file:

```
<PackList>
  <Header>
    <OrderNumber>PO12123</OrderNumber>
    <OrderQty>100</OrderQty>
  </Header>
  <Items>
    <Item>
      <PN>31023312</PN>
      <Color>Black</Color>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <PN>22023312</PN>
      <Color>White</Color>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <PN>44023312</PN>
      <Color>Blue</Color>
    </Item>
  </Items>
</PackList>
```

I'm able to read the `Header` part using below code:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public string PN { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public class PList
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public int OrderQty { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
}

(...)
PList PL = new PList();
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"c:/Test/PackList.xml"))
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing("OrderNumber");
    PList.OrderNumber = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
    reader.ReadToFollowing("OrderQty");
    PList.OrderQty = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
}
(...)
```

But I have no idea on how to read every `Item` within the `Items` tag.

Any advice?

Comment: Linq (from Xml to DTO) is much easier than XmlReader.  Is the source document huge?  Or can you load the whole xml into memory?  If so, see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498467/parent-children-xml-to-dto-object-model-with-linq

Comment: I use like my answer following posting.  I use a combination of XmlReader and Xml Linq. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503602/efficient-parsing-of-xml/37503653#37503653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reader.ReadToFollowing("OrderNumber");
plist.OrderNumber = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
reader.ReadToFollowing("OrderQty");
plist.OrderQty = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();

reader.ReadToFollowing("Items");

using (var innerReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
{
    while (innerReader.ReadToFollowing("PN"))
    {
        var item = new OrderItem();
        item.PN = innerReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        reader.ReadToFollowing("Color");
        item.Color = innerReader.ReadElementContentAsString();

        plist.OrderItems.Add(item);
    }
}

reader.ReadToFollowing("foo");
var foo = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
```

Where `foo` is tag name after the `Items`.

Don't forget `plist.OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();`

Comment: I was testing the same approach you posted, it works fine. But if there is another tag after the Items (Not the case posted) it won't be read since ReadToFollowing("PN") if false the XmlReader is in an end of file state.

Answer (score 1):

Use XmlNodeList

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

document.Load(@"c:/Test/PackList.xml");

XmlNodeList Items = document.GetElementsByTagName("Item");

foreach (XmlNode item in Items)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This pulls the entire document into memory.  XmlReader is the "firehose" way.

Comment: I wanted to do it using XmlReader if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Check out XmlReader.**ReadSubtree()** method.

> Returns a new XmlReader instance that can be used to read the current
>   node, and all its descendants.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree(v=vs.110).aspx

*Note :* Position of main reader might be also be moved, so you will continue at not exactly the position you were ReadToFollowing() got you.